# Postgres 12 - CREATE AGGREGATE looks right, but results never return

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've been wanting a reason to try out `CREATE AGGREGATE`, and now have one: Root Mean Square/Quadratic Mean. I posted some broken code, that I've corrected, based on helpful suggestions from [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes). Here's the working setup, with my custom `tools` and `types` schemas...you could use your own.

Now that it's working, I'm finding that the custom aggregate is **dramatically slower** than raw SQL. The grouping field is indexed, the aggregated field is not. Is this speed difference to be expected, and can it be overcome in SQL or PL/PgSQL?

First, here's the working code:

```
------------------------------------------------------
-- Create compound type to pass down processing chain
------------------------------------------------------
DROP TYPE types.rms_state CASCADE;

CREATE TYPE types.rms_state AS (
     running_count       int4,
     running_sum_squares int4
);

------------------------------------------------------
-- Create the per-row function
------------------------------------------------------
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tools.rms_row_function(types.rms_state, int4);

CREATE FUNCTION tools.rms_row_function (
    rms_data_in      types.rms_state,
    value_from_row   int4
)

RETURNS types.rms_state

LANGUAGE plpgsql 
IMMUTABLE
STRICT

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
   rms_data_out types.rms_state;

BEGIN

--    RAISE NOTICE    'rms_row_function: rms_data_in: %', rms_data_in::text;

  rms_data_out.running_count       := rms_data_in.running_count + 1;
  rms_data_out.running_sum_squares := rms_data_in.running_sum_squares + (value_from_row ^ 2);

  RETURN rms_data_out;

END;
$BODY$;

------------------------------------------------------
-- Create the final results function
------------------------------------------------------
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tools.rms_result_function(types.rms_state);

CREATE FUNCTION tools.rms_result_function (
    rms_data_in types.rms_state
)

RETURNS real

LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
STRICT

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
   rms_out real;

BEGIN

-- RAISE NOTICE    'rms_result_function: rms_data_in: %', rms_data_in::text;

IF (rms_data_in.running_count = 0) THEN
    rms_out := 0;
ELSE
   rms_out := (rms_data_in.running_sum_squares / rms_data_in.running_count)::real;
   rms_out := rms_out ^ 0.5; -- Get the square root and return it
END IF;

RETURN rms_out;

END;
$BODY$;

------------------------------------------------------
-- Create the aggregate bindings/declaration
------------------------------------------------------
CREATE AGGREGATE tools.rms (int4)
(
    sfunc     = tools.rms_row_function,
    finalfunc = tools.rms_result_function,

    stype     = types.rms_state,
                FINALFUNC_MODIFY = READ_WRITE,

    initcond = '(0,0)' -- Reset on each group, must be a textual version of state data.
);
```

I'm using a field named `analytic_productivity.num_inst` in my example, but it could be any `int4` field. Here's a stripped-down table declation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.analytic_productivity (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    facility_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    num_inst integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);
```

The `facility` table is included in the query for a name lookup:

```
select facility.name_                as facility_name,
       sqrt(avg(power(num_inst, 2))) as inst_rms, -- root mean square/quadratic mean,
       rms(num_inst)                 as inst_rms_check
   
  from analytic_productivity
left join facility on facility.id = analytic_productivity.facility_id

group by 1
order by 1
```

Below are some sample results.

```
+-----------------+--------------------+----------------+
| facility_name   | inst_rms           | inst_rms_check |
+-----------------+--------------------+----------------+
| Anderson        | 5.191804567965901  | 5.0990195      |
| Baldwin North   | 42.24082451064157  | 42.237423      |
| Curvey          | 41.75334367003306  | 41.749252      |
| Daodge Creeek   | 28.75910443926612  | 28.757608      |
| Edgards         | 42.430040392954375 | 42.426407      |
+-------------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

I'm not alarmed about the slight difference in scores, as I'm using a `real`, which only supports six decimals.

Comment: `**` is not the power operator, unless you created it.  In which case you should show it.

Comment: You don't set `initcond`, nor do you deal with rms_data starting out being NULL.  So this should not block, but it will return NULL for all inputs.